# onRequestPermissionsResult called in HomeActivity but not in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-permissions

In a fragment I call requestPermissions

```
public class FgDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},22);
```

In the HomeActivity. java I wrote this code which is working fine

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i("info", "Result recieved");
    }
```

but I want to get onRequestPermissionsResult on the FgDialogFragment class. I tried this but it's not working. There is a lot of similar topics but none of them helped me to solve my problem.

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
        Log.i("info", "Result recieved in fragment");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requestPermissions` call is only available within an Activity.  There is also an `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`, but that also takes an `Activity` context for the callback.

The callback will only work within an activity.  I suggest either you create a [listener](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) you can call into your fragment or use an [event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).