# onRequestPermissionsResult called with a different request code each time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I request permission in a fragment with this code

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},14);
```

and in my `HomeActivity` I use this code to get the result

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i("permission", "Request Code: "+ requestCode);}
```

if for example I set the code at `14`, I get as requestcode `65550` on `onRequestPermissionsResult`. If I deny permission request and than request it another time I get a different requestcode. This is the output of 5 `onRequestPermissionsResult` called with the same `requestPermissions` and with the code 14

```
Request Code: 65550
Request Code: 131086
Request Code: 196622
Request Code: 262158
Request Code: 327694
```

Comment: kindly post the code where you calling `startActivityForResult`

Comment: You can try and write on `onRequestPermissionsResult()`  in fragment and then i think it will work perfactly

Comment: it didn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729377/onrequestpermissionsresult-called-in-homeactivity-but-not-in-fragment/39733048#39733048

Comment: I don't understand why are you receiving result in `Activity` rather than `Fragment` ?

Comment: it didn't get called in the fragment, that's why I created the topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activity doesn't know which fragment is calling `startActivityForResult`

So if you are calling `startActivityForResult(intent, 1)`  from a fragment, you need to replace it with `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1)`

it will most probably solve your issue

Hope it helps.